# What is the "format" parameter used for in Django REST Framework views?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In the DRF documentation example [found here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/):

```
class SnippetList(APIView):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The above sample has an unused `format` parameter in both the `get()` and `post()` methods. I have stepped through the `rest_framework` source and I cannot find any instance where this parameter is handed off to the `get()` or `post()` method by the dispatcher. Is this parameter required to be present in the method definition? If so, what is it used for? When is it used?

Comment: Does the base class use it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found that the `format` parameter is used when you use [format suffixes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes/). So now I wanted to find out **how** this was used because nothing in the handler code seems to be using it but somehow it still works (magic behavior).

I went ahead and used `pdb` to trace execution of the view and found that `APIView.initial()` extracts this parameter from the `kwargs` and the uses it in the call to `APIView.perform_content_negotiation()` which selects the renderer and media type to use in the response.

Answer (score 6):

Basiclly this "format" parameter is used to define the output response [format](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#adding-optional-format-suffixes-to-our-urls), like: csv, json, etc

Comment: Yes. Documented in http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes/

Answer (score 0):

Consider example:
suppose you want the 'html' format of response which you receive  your api endpoint
So for this, you can easily make a query from the url itself like 
https://api.example.com/users/?format=html
Now if your views doesn't have the parameter as format=None then this could work.

But to disable this behaviour you must turn format=None